Is there a "nice" categorization of graphs of size $n$ whose automorphism group is $n!/O(n^4)$ or larger?
It is known that for graphs on $n$ vertices, only $K_n$ and the empty graph have the highest possible automorphism group size. It is also known that removing one edge from the complete graph (or adding one edge to the empty graph) gives you an automorphism group of size $n!/{n \choose 2}$. Some other results can be shown for removing two edges from the complete graph (adjacent or not).
I was wondering whether there is an integer $m$ such that for all $n \geq m$, all graphs on $n$ vertices with automorphism groups of size larger than, say $n!/n^4$ can be placed into $O(1)$ isomorphism classes.
Edit: As pointed out, my question lacks clarity. Suppose each graph is represented by a symmetric $0/1$ adjacency matrix with $0$s along the diagonal. Given a graph $G$, we define the isomorphism class $\mathcal{C}$ containing $G$ as the set of all graphs isomorphic to $G$ with distinct adjacency matrices. And in particular, $n! = |\textit{Aut}(G)||\mathcal{C}|$ whenever the graph $G$ belongs to the isomorphism class $\mathcal{C}$.

What is your definition of an isomorphism class? We could argue that the set of graph with more than $n!/n^4$ automorphisms are an automorphism class...

This is not so hard to show that we need an orbit of size at least $n-4$, inducing a symmetric subgroup, to get $\mathcal{(n-4)!}$ automorphisms. So either these vertices form a clique or an independent set. By complementation, we can just consider these form an independent set. We just need to consider the possible edges between the at most $4$ remaining vertices and whether each of these vertices is linked to none or all of the "at least $n-4$"vertices.

@caduk thank you for the response. Could you expand a little on the first part? What arguments/lemma imply this? My apologies because I'm not top well versed with group actions related arguments, etc other than basic stuff like orbit stabilizer, burnsides lemma. Out of curiosity, do similar results hold for (n-3)! and (n-2)!?
